# JavaScript onbeforeunload() function not submiting form

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I have a form called "myForm" that I install handler into in order to capture the form data when the form is moved off of.  What I find is the form data is not posted when the user moves away from the form.  onchange works but does not capture data when the form is left.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function saveForm()
{
    alert("saveForm");
    document.myForm.submit();
}
window.onbeforeunload = saveForm;
//window.onchange = saveForm;
```

2nd example:

Here's another example. Press the Yahoo link with and without entering data in the edit field causes 2 different reactions

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function unloadTest() { alert("unloadTest"); }
function changeTest() { alert("changeTest"); } 

window.onbeforeunload = unloadTest

window.onchange = changeTest 

</script>

<form name="myForm">

<A href="yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
<br> 
<input type="text" name="foo">
</form>
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that, for security reasons. Furthermore, even if you can, you _should not_.

Comment: Can't save form data when leaving a form for security reasons?   I don't know what that means.

Comment: What I mean is you can't do very much with `onbeforeunload` to prevent malicious code from being run when someone tries to leave a page. Furthermore, you __should not submit a form for the user__. If they are leaving the page, they have not submitted the form, and the data in it is not yours to take.

Comment: @Mathletics, This is not true, he can do that, but because the request is async, the request will abort.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the request is async, and when the tab closed, it abort.

This is bad practice, but you can do it with synchronized request.

For example:

```
window.onbeforeunload= function() {
    var myForm = $('#myForm');
    var request = myForm.serialize();
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST','www.example.com/submit',false); // false for synchronized request
    xhr.send(request);
}
```

When the user will close the tab, the page will stop until the response from server will return.

When you use Synchronous XMLHttpRequest you get in console (Chrome and FF) warning - "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/."

The best practice is to use the main mean of onbeforeunload. For example:

```
var hasChanges = false;
var myForm = $('#myForm');
myForm.on('change',function() {
    hasChanges = true;
});

window.onbeforeunload= function() {
    if (notSubmit) {
        return ('You have unsaved changes,'); // or whatever
    }
}
```

Sorry about my english...

Comment: Well, this is more involved than I envisioned.  Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

writing code like that is the same as using window.location on mouseover which would basically redirect them when they hover on a link or button. Browsers block that kind of thing. **My suggestion to you would be to store and retrieve the form data using the localStorage API**.  What you wrote is bad javascript.

I am sure most browsers will not allow it to submit using before unload because the before unload event is fired when you are trying to leave the page or close the browser window. Forcing a submit on that event even if it was allow is not good. localStorage will allow you to populate the form with with data when the user returns with is much more ethical.

Using the Async Request would fix some of the issue you are having but its still not a good thing to do.

Comment: That would not allow the data to be saved when the form is moved away from.  Even the alert dialog doesn't display

Comment: I have used that code before you may want to try to use a confirm() instead of an alert. That is legal javascript. Basically what that will do is let them know they are about to leave the page or site and if they click the cancel they won't leave the page. That is a better option. I will post the code if you want.

Comment: When I make a change to the settings on an Android or iPhone I don't have to save the changes; they are just saved.

Comment: that sounds like a good way to handle it.  An example would be helpful.  Thanks.